# Find the $k$-th derivative at certain point of a function that is given definition on discrete points

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Suppose $f$ is a real function on $[-1, 1]$ that satisfies

(1) $f(\frac{1}{n})=\ln{(1+2n)}-\ln{n}, n=1,2,\cdots$;

(2) derivative of any order exists;

(3) $\exists M>0$ such that $\left|f^{(n)}(x)\right|\le n!M$.

Find $f^{(k)}(0), k=0,1,\cdots$.

---

**Background**: This is an exercise from some mathematical analysis textbook that is confusing me. Hope someone could help me figure this out.

**Relevant definitions**: $\ln$ - natural logarithm.

**My current progress**:

Since $f$ is continuous, $f(0)=f(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\ln\frac{1+2n}{n}}=\ln2$.

And follow the definition of derivative we have $f'(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}{\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{(n\ln\frac{1+2n}{n}-n\ln2)}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{n\ln(1+\frac{1}{2n})}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{n\cdot\frac{1}{2n}}=\frac{1}{2}.$
$f''(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0}{\frac{f'(h)-f'(0)}{h}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\color{red}{f'(1/n)}-f'(0)}{1/n}}$

...and I found no way to deal with $f'(1/n)$.

A very intuitive idea is that from condition (1) above we have

$f(x)=\ln{(2+x)}$

this is true for all $x=1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\cdots$, so we can tell that on some neiborhood of $0$ (say $U$), $f(x)=\ln{(2+x)}$$\Rightarrow$$f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln{(2+x)}=\frac{1}{2+x}$. Then we get $f^{(k)}(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}^k}{{\mathrm{d}x}^k}\ln{(2+x) (x\in U)}$, and the question become very easy. But I have no clue how to prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties 2 and 3 ensure that $f$ is an analytic function. Property 1 ensures that it concides with $x \mapsto \log(2+x)$ on a set that has a cluster point in $[-1, 1]$, i.e., $\{\frac{1}{n} | n \ge 1\}$. By the identity principle for analytic functions, they should agree everywhere on $[-1, 1]$. This confirms your intuitive idea.